# Where would an R rmd file be autosaved?

Tags: r, autosave

Where would an autosaved rmd file be on my computer? I've unlocked hidden files on my mac and then looked in unsaved notebooks within my rproj- but the only version of my rmd is from 6th september. I closed down r studio today without saving (stupidly) as I tried opening a new rmd file but it was hanging. I didn't save first and so have potentially lost 5 hours of work on an RMD file. Any help greatly appreciated.
Nicky (have tried searching on here first so please excuse if there is an answer I didn't find)

Comment: It'd probably save in your working directory, I'd reckon.

Comment: Was it a named file? If so, Spotlight shld be able to find it. If not, did RStudio come back up completely blank or just this file missing? If the former, there may be a background RStudio process running that you can't see (a reboot and re-open of RStudio may restore your file). If the latter, there's little chance that the file is salvageable. However, you may be able to rebuild the code from it w/RStudio's "history" pane.

Comment: It is a named file created on the 6/09 worked on yesterday and sunday. But I've checked in .Rstudio-desktop and in my GitHub project files .Rproj.user under unsaved notebooks - can't find anything more recent than the 6th. I left my laptop on with RStudio open but asleep inbetween work sessions- I must have just not saved it since 6th and there is no autosave on the rmd files that I can find. I saved an image from tableau to be embedded in the file in my images folder last night and that is there (so not going completely mad;)...I'l have to chalk this up to experience.

Comment: Recently I had a similar issue as I deleted a triky function out of my script. I'm actually a windows user and could solve my issue by searching by containing text of the file. I searched for a known code snipped related to the function and found it. It was a little crypty because it was fount in kinda R history file as @hrbrmstr described but I could copy/paste it. The tool is called [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack), for mac you could look [here](https://alternativeto.net/software/agent-ransack/?platform=mac) eventually. Good luck!

Comment: If you use RStudio, it maintains a history database that's more extensive than R's own .Rhistory. There are posts on SO showing how to retrieve the contents.